# How to make an external request in azure mobile services from custom web api

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to make an external request from my custom azure mobile services web api.
   I know that it runs node js so I searched for solution....I came up with this solutia:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {

    var http = require('http');

    http.get("YOURSITE", 
    function(res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    }); 

    response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'YOURMESSAGE' });
};

  I get the following message: connect EACCES which means that I don't have the right permission... Besided this, I went to the configure tab in my mobile service and added at The Cross-origin resource sharing MYSITE, but I was pretty sure it won't help...
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't attentive and I put my local ip adress and thats why I didn't have acess. This works fine with external ips.